# Scala Script Error on MAC OSX

Tags: scala

I am receiving the following errors when I try to run a sample Hello world in Scala. The file has this statement saved in it.  println("Hello World from a Scala Script!"). How to avoid these errors?

```
Sandeeps-MacBook-Pro:ScalaScripts sandeep$ scala Hello.scala
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:1: error: not found: value \
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf370
 ^
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:3: error: not found: value \
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red38\green38\blue38;}
 ^
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:3: error: not found: value \
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red38\green38\blue38;}
           ^
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:3: error: not found: value \
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red38\green38\blue38;}
                                    ^
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:4: error: not found: value \
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
^
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala:8: error: not found: value \
\f0\fs24 \cf2 println("Hello World from a Scala Script!")}
^
6 errors found
```

Comment: Can you show your script code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong

look at this line

```
/Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts/Hello.scala
```

and then at this

```
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
```

Unix-like systems are using forward slash `/` in its paths

Also it looks like your path in the script written not as a string path wrapped in `"your path"` and Scala compiler is tries to use it as a some value

Comment: I am new to scala.I installed it using HomeBrew. Now I was following a tutorial and I copied println("Hello World from a Scala Script!") into a .rtf file in mac and changed it back to .scala file.From Terminal I reached the directory which is /Users/sandeep/Documents/ScalaScripts and typed in scala Hello.scala which returned me the above error. I tried to run the command directly in terminal without using a script and it worked fine.

Comment: @user1757018 it looks that the problem is that you created an `.rtf` file, try to create `.txt` file and then change it to `.scala`